# Batch to list folders and sub folders to separate lists

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have a root folder "ROOT"
inside it there a folders with dates and each one has sub folders
i want to get a list of each folders with the name of the subfolders inside them but without the path, saved to a txt file to csv but the name of the file will be the folder name. so for instance if the folder is "1.1" "2.1" and the subfolders inside are "sub1, sub2 and co
ill have a text file named 1.1.txt with sub1 , sub2 , 2.1.txt and so
Inside the folder structure is like this

**1.1**

- Sub folder1a
- Sub folder2a

**2.1**

1.Sub folder1b

1.Sub folder2b

this is what i have so far

```
for %%G in (.) do set curpath=%%~nxG
dir /b /s /a:d >%curpath%.txt
```

so i get a file with the current folder name and all sub folders but with the paths that i dont want.
and also i dont want it in one file i want to know exactly what sub folders in each folder.
thinking about it saving it in some way to excel with column of what folders are in each folders is a real help which is what i really need

Answer (score 1):

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\09\08\SO_46118986.cmd
@Echo off 

CD /D A:\Root

for /R %%A in (.) Do (
    PushD  "%%A"
    Del "%%~nxA.txt" >Nul 2>&1
    For /F "delims=" %%B in (
        'Dir /B/AD 2^>Nul ^|Find /V ""'
    ) Do Echo:%%~nxB >>"%%~nxA.txt"
    PopD
)
```

- `For /r` with a single dot `(.)` enumerates all (sub-)directories . See `for /?`or read [for /r](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html).
- `Pushd/Popd` step into directory and store location on a stack / restore previous location.
- Since the dir appends to a file we have to ensure it's empty otherwise it would grow on succesive runs. So the file is deleted first. The `>NUL 2>&1` suppresses possible errormessages if the file doesn't exist and normal output of this command.
- `For /f` with ('command') parses the output of command. See `for /?` or read [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).
- `"delims="` will cause no splitting at default delimiter space.

Sample output on simulated tree structure:

```
> tree . /F
ROOT
│   root.txt
│
├───1.1
│   │   1.1.txt
│   │
│   ├───Sub folder 1a
│   └───Sub folder 2a
└───2.1
    │   2.1.txt
    │
    ├───Sub folder 1b
    └───Sub folder 2b

> for /r %A in (*.txt) Do type %A
> type .\root\root.txt
1.1
2.1

> type .\root\1.1\1.1.txt
Sub folder 1a
Sub folder 2a

> type .\root\2.1\2.1.txt
Sub folder 1b
Sub folder 2b
```

Comment: Wow cool :) can you explain each line so ill understand, also what i need to change to have all the text files in the current directory and not in each folder?

Comment: See extended answer, To output all text files in current folder at the cmdline `for %A in (*.txt) do @Type "%A"` In a batch file double the percent signs.

Comment: I still dont understand the first and second lines why i need them and all these parts with 2^>Nul ^|Find /V ""'

Comment: The :: is for my convenience, the echo off is hopefully selfexplaining, The cd /d changes drive and directory to the root. I removed the setlocal (a habit) not necessary here. BTW **ALL* commands can be looked up in a cmd window with command /? or at [ss64.com/nt](https://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: Yeah i talked about second line cause brfore there was a `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` i looked at ss64.com thats how i came with the first commands i wrote im just learning this , but i cant find there nothing about `2^>Nul ^|Find /V ""'` and the `null` commands also i tried your `for %A in (*.txt) do @Type "%A"` im the script but it just write on screen whats in the text files and not save them in the current directory

Comment: @jjj see thee [Syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html) section at SS64. Look at "Redirection".

Comment: @LotPings where do i put `for %A in (*.txt) do @Type "%A"` i tried it but didnt work

Comment: That cmd line is just to check  the resulting text files in the current folder from an open cmd window.

Comment: I understand that but how an i save all the text output from the batch in the same directory?

Comment: @LotPings How can i save these text files in the current directory i cant find an answer on this? also is it complicated make changes to this script to get this results in a csv file with column of each folder and its correct sub folders under it or should i open a new question?